# PDF extraction not complete

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to extract text from the PDF file: http://www.filedropper.com/copy_1, but I get less than half of text from a page.
I'm using iTextSharp:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
string currentText =  PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1);
```

I have used SimpleTextExtractionStrategy as well instead of default LocationTextExtractionStrategy:

```
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy())
```

The file was originally generated from Microsoft Reporting Service (to which I don't have an access), and that I've extracted one page for testing the text extraction.

Anyone can help with that?

Comment: Your PDF simply does not contain the information required for text extraction according to the PDF specification. Try copy&paste from Adobe Reader for the text sections you are missing and you will see that it will fail, too. Microsoft Reporting Service has a long history of creating PDFs insufficient for text extraction.

Comment: Furthermore, when posting code, please do so in a sensible way. The code you posted creates a PDF reader and an extraction strategy which are not used for anything, and the text extractor then extracts from some stamper's reader using the default extraction strategy...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've fixed the insensible code, as You asked.
How can it not contain the information (like the numeric values) if acrobat reader displays it?

Comment: *"How can it not contain the information (like the numeric values) if acrobat reader displays it?"* - When Acrobat *displays* a glyph, it merely means that it has found some instructions how a glyph shall be *painted* but it does not automatically mean that it knows which Unicode character that glyph represents. But regular text extraction is about mapping to Unicode characters, not painting (unless you OCR).

Comment: *"like the numeric values"* - the numeric values used in encodings of embedded fonts can be very non-standard. E.g. one often finds embedded fonts for single pages where the first glyph drawn on some page gets the code 01, the second (not identical) one gets 02, the third (not identical) one 03, etc. and the embedded font is just sorted like that. In such a situation the PDF viewer can easily paint all glyphs (the font data is embedded after all) but not at all extract meaning (i.e. Unicode strings) unless there is extra information, e.g. a proper **ToUnicode** map.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
StringBuilder currentText= new StringBuilder();
for (int i= 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    currentText.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
}
```

and then perform whatever operation you want on "currentText".

Comment: There's only one page in the PDF. Looping over all the pages in the document won't help. As @mkl indicates, this is a "Garbage In, Garbage Out" problem: the text can't even be extracted using copy/paste in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Your proposal effectively is to iterate over all the PDF pages instead of only looking at the first. As the OP's sample document has only one page, this won't make the tiniest bit of a difference. In contrast to the OP's code, though, your code at least is consistent...

Comment: You definitely are right. Actually, I have not checked the .pdf file itself. Just posted a better code for what he has done so far.

Comment: In that case, you should delete your answer. I have flagged it as "very low quality."

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: First it is a better code than the one he has given and second if you know the answer why don't you answer his question ?

Comment: Because the question has already been answered in the comments.